# Can i direct user to a specific folder depending on

Tags: php

Can i direct user to a specific folder depending on what domain they requested?

I have several domains at no-ip.org, lets say NAME1.no-ip.org and NAME2.no-ip.org. In my default web folder i have two sub folders, one of each of the domains. Could I in any way redirect them to the correct folder depending on what domain they are trying to browse?

If it matters i have set up ISS7 with PHP :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "NAME1.no-ip.org") 
  header("Location: /right/folder");
```

BTW Look also how to deal with virtualhost and IIS7.
Usually this kinds of redirection are made by the webserver itself if well configured